# Does appengine Key.createKey(kind, id) return always the same result?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

`public static Key createKey(java.lang.String kind, long id)`

Returns always the same key for same input values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Generating Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Generating_keys) in [Entities, Properties and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities), CreateKey(string, long) should be deterministic, and much software relies on that fact.  Many things would break if that key generator was unstable.

Comment: Well, I can't believe that I have to rely on sombody elses opinion in such a basic matters. Why they just dont write this information to the APIs? Non of the pages you mentioned contains words deterministic, stable, idempotent.... in the context of this method. Therefore, I can not accept first part of your answer.

Comment: Yes the docs do not explain the concept in enough detail.  I re-read the entire linked page and the only sentence that helps a little is "Because it is part of the entity's key, the identifier is associated permanently with the entity and cannot be changed" but that still leaves the reader to conclude that both an entity's identifier and its key are immutable.  I probably came to accept the determinism of the algorithm from intuition after using the Datastore, rather than an explicit definition. Would you like to [file an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) about it?

Comment: Here is the issue https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10704